# What strategy should I use to get "Insane Bolt"?

Tags: plague-inc

There is an achievement called "Insane Bolt" that requires to beat the game with Bacteria in less than 365 days. I want to beat it on Brutal.
My strategy proved to be close to the goal (around 400 days), but not quite reaching the goal.
My strategy was of starting in India, evolving until I reached Skin Lesions, then evolving Water 1 and 2, Drug Resistance, Air 1 and 2 and Extreme Bioaerosol, Bird 1 and 2, etc. It proved to be a very fast-paced strategy, but hasn't yet reach its goal.
**What strategy should I use to beat the game with Bacteria on Brutal, without pre-modifying genetic code or using cheats?**

Comment: if your strategy is good, play it on easier difficulties.

Answer (score 2):

From [It's Spicy's blog](http://icspicy.blogspot.com/2014/08/plague-incsubmitted-guide-ice-age.html) (The strategy was written for Mega Brutal, but should work on Brutal just fine):

Ice Age Mega-Brutal:Bacteria

I have tried other plague types on the Ice Age scenario but they always fail to infect Iceland and Greenland quick enough. So I though if I use the Bacteria’s special abilities together with Cold 1 and 2, it should help. Getting Extreme Bioaerosol early helps to get those 2 countries infected as early as possible. Necrosis helps infection in those 2 countries as the dead people also infect. That’s all. Thanks!

### Gene Setup

```
ATP Boost
Aquacyte
Sympto-Stasis
Darwinist
Extremopile
```

1. Before start, evolve

   - Nausea
   - Rash
   - Sweating
2. Start in India (3 Aug 2014) the date signifies the time he started, just to clear that up.
3. Evolve the following as soon as you have the required DNA

   - Cysts
   - Abscesses
   - Vomiting
   - Coughing - Projectile vomiting combo likely to pop to increase infectivity
   - Pneumonia
   - Anaemia
   - Haemophilia
   - Sneezing
   - Hypersensitivity
   - Skin Lesions

(16 Oct 2014) (1.4 mil infected in India)

4. Evolve

   - Water 1
   - Air 1
   - Baterial Resilience 1 and 2

(30 Nov 2014)

5. Evolve

   - Water 2
   - Air 2
   - Extreme Bioaerosol
6. Evolve Bird 1, get ready to pop a lot of red biohazards (3 Jan 2015)
7. Evolve Bacterial Resilience 3
8. Evolve Cold Resistance 1, Drug Resistance 1, Cold Resistance 2
9. Evolve Bird 2, Livestock 1, Drug 2
10. Evolve Diarrhoea, Dysentery, Necrosis (so the corpses can infect the living)
11. Evolve Insanity and Coma to increase infectivity within Greenland and Iceland, as well as slow cure progress. Paralysis and Fever help, too. (1 Apr 2015)
12. Monitor the infection of Greenland and Iceland. Evolve Livestock 2 if necessary
13. "There are no healthy people left in the world" - 1 May 2015
14. Evolve Total Organ Failure, Hemorrhagic Shock, Internal Haemorrhaging
15. Stats

    - **Time**: 320 Days (Insane Bolt achievement)
    - **Score** 74795 (3 Biohazards)

Comment: Really?! With my fast-paced strategy I've got 4 Biohazards. (I'm not sure if I've did it with Bacteria or with Virus)

Comment: This worked perfectly... great strategy!